# Padding a CountVectorizer() in skLearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

So I am using CountVecotrizer() function in sklearn to help me create a model prediction for work.

The goal for the project is to take a job description and classify it within a certain category. My goal is to take each row and have it so that the model gets fed up to certain about of "tokens" (words) so that it can accurately predict the classification.

For example: if row 1 has 20 words in the string, than I want all the rows to have 20 words in them so I would need to either add more 0s to end of the array or shorten the array if there is too much words. I was thinking of defining a Max_Length in python to make it easier for me.

Was wondering how would I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CountVectorizer` already does what the question proposes, it's just less obvious when looking at the sparse matrix outputs. If we convert them back to dense matrices it should be more obvious:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

X_raw = ["every word in this sentence is unique"]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
print(vectorizer.fit_transform(X_raw).todense())
```

Output with comments:

```
# Every word is used once
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

If there is a word that appears in one string but not another, it will be represented with a `0`:

```py
X_raw = [
    "every word in this sentence is unique",
    "every word in this sentence is unique too too",
]

print(vectorizer.fit_transform(X_raw).todense())
```

Output with comments:

```
#             ----- The word 'too' was not used in the first sentence,
#            /      but it was used twice in the second sentence.
#           v
[[1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1]]
```